# return to login page for every request!! laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, middleware

i login to application dashboard successfully and have no problem in authentication but after that when i click on another link in the page, again return me to login page. by mean for every request take me to login page!?
please help

my web routes:

Auth::routes();

```
    Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'auth'] , function() {

        Route::get('admin', function() {
         return view('master'); 
        });

        Route::get('admin/categories','CategoryController@index')->name('categories.index');
        Route::get('admin/categories/create','CategoryController@create')->name('categories.create');
        Route::post('admin/categories/store','CategoryController@store')->name('categories.store');
        Route::get('admin/categories/edit/{id}','CategoryController@edit')->name('categories.edit');
        Route::post('admin/categories/update/{id}','CategoryController@update')->name('categories.update');
        Route::delete('admin/categories/delete/{id}','CategoryController@destroy')->name('categories.destroy');
    });
```

Comment: You're using `'middleware' => 'auth'` for all the routes. If you're being redirected back to the login page every time, I'd check if your user is really authenticated after login with `Auth::check()`.

Comment: also, where is your `dashboard` route?

Comment: lesssugar ,,
 after login when going to the login page again it asks me to log in again !! ,,,, that means the user doesn't authenticate after the first-time login ?

Comment: HCK ,,, dashboard route is get('admin')

Answer (score 1):

As far as the details you've provided, I can already see that you have not added `web` middleware group to your route group.

The `web` middleware group is responsible for things such as encrypting cookies, verifying CSRF token and starting session.

In `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

So, most likely the issue is that you haven't started a session, therefore logging in only works for one request.

Apply the `web` middleware group to your route group and it should solve the issue:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {

    Route::get('admin', function () {
        return view('master');
    });

    Route::get('admin/categories', 'CategoryController@index')->name('categories.index');
    Route::get('admin/categories/create', 'CategoryController@create')->name('categories.create');
    Route::post('admin/categories/store', 'CategoryController@store')->name('categories.store');
    Route::get('admin/categories/edit/{id}', 'CategoryController@edit')->name('categories.edit');
    Route::post('admin/categories/update/{id}', 'CategoryController@update')->name('categories.update');
    Route::delete('admin/categories/delete/{id}', 'CategoryController@destroy')->name('categories.destroy');
});
```

Comment: Gustavs Rācenājs ,, when applied (web) middleware the same issue ask me to log in each every request>

Comment: my code In kernel.php
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

Comment: I try to check if the admin really authenticated or not but when I log in and try to change URL to the login page again asks me to log in again like first time

Comment: What you're trying to say is that after you've already loged in and you go to the login page again, you see the login form? Then you have to apply the `guest` middleware to the login page in order to prevent users from accessing guest-only pages.

Comment: thanks the problem solved,,,  on header view the  <a>{{Auth::logout()}} </a>  was running every request,,,, change to {{yrl('logout') }} and working fine thanks